# Custom Jigsaw Puzzle

Tags: puzzle-creation

I would like a custom jigsaw puzzle for my husband. he loves large puzzles (2000+ pcs) and he loves large cats (lions, tigers, etc) Can anyone tell me where I can get a photo enlarged and a custom puzzle created? Or, how I can cut one myself. I have a laser cutter at work, but the format is only  24" x 18" x 8.5". I would like to be able to cut the puzzle in sections, but can't wrap my brain around it.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's more of a 'shopping' question than a puzzling question.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Puzzling.SE! To be perfectly honest, this page is generally focused on creating and solving puzzles online; so this question is a little off-topic. That said, I did a quick Google search for you and found a bunch of websites that could possibly help you out: [the link is here](https://www.google.ca/search?q=custom+jigsaw+puzzle+creator&rlz=1C1GGRV_enCA795CA795&oq=custom+jigsaw+puzzle+creator&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j0l5.6350j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). I've never done this before, so I'd like to help you out further but I can't really recommend one website over another. It seems that at least a few of these websites will help you with what you need! Good luck and happy puzzling!